# Цикл for проходящий по итераторам

Tags: c++, c++11

**Проблема**:
Синтаксическая конструкция цикла for для итераторов стандартна.

```
   // code
   for(auto it = p; it != q; ++it){...}
   // another code
```

И это, кажется, работало. Но я столкнулся с тем, что условие it != q не проходит в коде ниже. Просто не срабатывает и происходит обращение за пределы контейнера. Знаю, что end указывает ЗА последний элемент, но как это мешает работе?

```
template<class FwdIt>
FwdIt remove_nth(FwdIt p, FwdIt q, size_t n)
{
// smth
        for (auto it = ++p; it != q;++it)
        {
            auto next = p; 
            *p = *++next; 
            p = next;
        }
//smth
}
```

Вызов происходит так:

```
std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
v.erase(remove_nth(v.begin(), v.end(), 5), v.end());
```

**Впорос:** 
Что я делаю не так? Я пропустил что-то существенное в освоении работы с итераторами?
Про range-based знаю, но здесь он не годен.

Comment: Что-то меня вообще смущают конструкции типа `*p = *(++p);` - гуру, подскажите, как это теперь - вроде не UB, но как работать будет?.. Да и выход за границы диапазона явно наблюдается...

Comment: Вот зачем вам это `*p = *(++p);`? Я почти уверен, что это неопределенное поведение. Сделали бы просто `auto next = p; *p = *++next; p = next;`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, Вы правы, так будет корректно. Но это не устраняет проблему.

Comment: А это потому, что `++next` может быть равна `q` (т. е. `end()`).

Comment: Стало еще "страньше" (с). `p` не меняется. Кстати, с чего вы решили, что "it != q не проходит"? В чем это выражается? Цикл бесконечный или что?

Comment: @Harry напутал с выходом за границы, поэтому и решил. что условие не проходит.

Comment: а если на словах, что должно делать `remove_nth()` и/или вся эта конструкция с `erase`'ом?

Comment: @Fat-Zer remove_nth() переносит элемент, который n номера, в конец. erase подчищает его.

Comment: А не вариант просто использовать `v.erase(std::next(v.begin(), n));`. Это ведь работает с любым контейнером.

Answer (score 3):

> remove_nth() переносит элемент, который n номера, в конец. erase подчищает его.

Удалить N-й элемент вектора:

```
v.erase(v.begin()+N);
```

Удалить K элементов начиная с N-го

```
v.erase(v.begin()+N, v.begin()+N+K);
```

> remove_nth() переносит элемент, который n номера, в конец.

Как-то так:

```
template<class FwdIt>
FwdIt moveNToEnd(FwdIt p, FwdIt q, size_t n) {
  assert (std::distace (p,q) < n);

  std::advance (p, n);
  auto val = *p;
  FwdIt prev = p++;
  for (;p!= q;) {
    *prev++ = *p++; 
  }
  *prev = val;

  return prev
}
```

*Замечания:*

- Для других контейнеров (`std::list`) можно сделать это более эффективно.
- Более практичным вариантом было бы сразу передавать итератор на перемещаемый элемент.

Comment: Хорошее предложение, такой тривиальный способ я запомню. Но он не подходит для моих целей. Я учусь и моей задачей является написание конкретно функции remove_nth(), которая должна переносить n эл-т в конец.

Comment: ну а почему не  просто v.erase(v.begin()+5)?????

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, нуда, меня почему-то переклинило...

Comment: добавил вариант аналогичный тому что был в ответе @Harry.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибки в вашей функции очевидные, вам об этом рассказали в комментарих. Функция пишется просто:

```
template<class FwdIt>
FwdIt remove_nth(FwdIt p, FwdIt q, const size_t n)
{
    FwdIt first = p + n; // нужно сохранять значение начала `p`
    for (auto it = first + 1; it != q;++it)
       *first++ = *it;
    return first;
}
```

Я думаю вам нужна отдельная функция, не требующая дальнейшее использование методов  контейнера для удаления элемента:
 Приведу  пример:

```
template<class ClassType, class For = typename ClassType::iterator>
ClassType my_remove(ClassType& cont, For p, For q, const size_t n)
{

    if(typeid(typename std::iterator_traits<For>::iterator_category)
            != typeid(std::random_access_iterator_tag) || size_t(q - p) <= n)
        return cont;
    For It = std::remove(p, q, n);
    //или используйте вашу собственную функцию
    //  For It = remove_nth(p, q, n);
    return ClassType(p, It);;
}

int main()
{  
    std::vector<int> v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10},
            res = my_remove(v, v.begin(), v.end(), 4); 
    for (int i : res)
        cout << i << ' ';   

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Цикл можно было оформить так. Полностью соответствует требуемому.
*В std::cout отладочный вывод*

```
    auto last = p;
        if (p != q) {
            for (auto it = ++p; it != q; ++it)
            {
                std::cout << " before: it " << *it << "; last " << *last << std::endl;
                std::swap(*last, *it);
                std::cout << "after: it " << *it << "; last " << *last << std::endl;
                ++last;
                p = it;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо всем ответившим на мой вопрос. Понимание проблемы пришло как раз благодаря ответам выше.